# sorting csv data according to occurrences of common words

Tags: php, csv

I have a large data coming from a csv file which looks something like below.

```
url1, comment1
url2, comment2
```

I need to find the common words between the comments and sort the rows accordingly based on the occurrence of the common words on each row.

At the moment I am able to get the common words but I'm lost as to how to sort the rows per common word without exhausting the memory.

Below is my very inefficient code.

```
$data = array();
while (($row = fgetcsv($fh, 1024, ',')) !== false) {
  $data[] = $row[1];
}

$str = preg_replace('/\s\s+/', ' ', trim(str_replace(array('!', '?', '.', ','), ' ', implode('', $data))));

$words = explode(" ", $str);
var_dump(array_count_values($words));
```

Comment: If you're going to be slicing/dicing the CSV data repeatedly, you'd be better off loading it into a database instead of doing it within PHP. The one-time loading cost would be offset by how much easier the data mining will be once it's in the database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Load the exploded data/words into database sounds like a good idea,

**OR** you can try this:

```
$summary = array();
$data = array();
while (($row = fgetcsv($fh, 1024, ',')) !== false) 
{
  $data[] = $row[1];
  $str    = preg_replace('/\s\s+/', ' ', trim(str_replace(array('!', '?', '.', ','), ' ', $row[1])));
  $words  = explode(" ", $str); 
  foreach ($words as $word)
  {
    $word = strtolower($word); // lowercase to reduce variations
    $summary[$word]++;
  }
}
/* variable $summary will contains all your count */
/* take note on the size of $summary, could growth quite big */
```

Comment: Is there a difference between using a separate $summary array and calling array_count_values($words)?

Comment: your method is do a comparison on whole csv (single execution cycle require lots of resources), while this compare line-by-line is break-down into multiple execution cycles with each cycle require very small resources